# Set specific animator-state as more important

Tags: unity, c#, animator

I have a animator with 3 states:

- KnifeWalk
- KnifeIdle
- KnifeAttack

[image: Animator]

The `KnifeAttack` state should be run, whenever the bool "Attack" is set to true. This always happens when the player presses the `Fire1` button (e.g. Left Mouse Button):

```
if (Input.GetButton("Fire1") && canAttack)
{
    canAttack = false;
    Invoke("AllowAttack", fireRate);

    animator.SetBool("Attack", true);
    Invoke("DisableAttackAnimation", fireRate/2);
}
```

`canAttack` is just a `bool` to control how fast the player can attack. The `float` variable `fireRate` holds the time, until the player can attack again.

However, sometimes the KnifeAttack state isn't triggered. The `Attack` variable is always set to `true`, when i press the `left mousebutton` while testing.

In the first screenshot you can see, how i set the transition between KnifeIdle and KnifeAttack. The transition between KnifeWalk and KnifeAttack is the same.

This is the transition between KnifeIdle and KnifeWalk:

[image]

And the transition between KnifeWalk and KnifeIdle:

[image]

What i would like to know is: Is there a way to set the attack-state to more important than the other states, so that it could be triggered everytime?

During testing i had it that about every 20 mouse clicks the attack-animation is not triggered, altough the Attack-variable is set to true correctly.

I also tried to change the `fireRate` times, but this doesn't seem to be the error.